# это же работа с указателем?

Tags: ассемблер

интересует такой код. есть локальная переменная `var_10`. `var_10` получает результат функции как указатель на строку.

```
mov [rbp+var_10], rax
```

после этого происходит вот это.

```
add [rbp+var_10], 4
```

я правильно понимаю, что `[rbp+var_10]` это не разыменовыванием указателя, а взятие адреса. тогда в этом коде `add [rbp+var_10], 4` означает, что указатель смещается на 4 байта вправо? ведь процессор не может работать в режиме `данные` & `данные`.

Comment: `add память, константа` отлично работает. И кстати никакого указателя (который хранился бы где либо, кроме регистра), тут вообще нет. var_10 в данном случае смещение относительно rbp, который выставлен при входе в функцию. так что это что то вроде [rbp+100], соответственно "сдвинуть" это никуда нельзя. Так что это просто `var_10+=4`

Comment: @Mike хорошо, спасибо.